# An integral ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ prime to $\mathfrak{m}$, such that $\mathfrak{am}^{-1}$ is principal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $\mathfrak{m}$ is a nonzero integral ideal in the Dedekind domain $O_K$. The problem is to

> find an integral ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ prime to $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $\mathfrak{am}^{-1}$ is principal.

For any two nonzero integral ideals $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{c} \ $ I can find an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is prime to $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{ac}$ is principal. As I understand, the fractional ideal $m^{-1}$ is not necessary integral, so I cannot just put $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{m}^{-1}$. However, by definition of a fractional ideal there is an element $\delta \in O_K$ such that $\delta \mathfrak{m}^{-1} \subset O_K$. So I can try to set $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{c} = \delta \mathfrak{m}^{-1}$. But now I do not know if $\delta \mathfrak{a}$ is prime to $\mathfrak{m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be prime to $\mathfrak{m}$ such that 
$$\mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{n}=(\beta)$$ now let 
$\mathfrak{a}$ also relatively prime to $\mathfrak{m}$ be such that 
$$\mathfrak{n}\mathfrak{a}=(\alpha)$$

Then $$(\frac{\alpha}{\beta})=\frac{\mathfrak{n}\mathfrak{a}}{\mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{n}}=\frac{\mathfrak{a}}{\mathfrak{m}}$$

Comment: My pleasure....